# Confusion about checkboxes in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I currently have an SVG with multiple groups, each containing a circle and text element that are both showing up, and I am trying to append a checkbox to each group. I understand these need to be wrapped in foreignObject tags, and so I am trying to append the checkboxes using the following code:

```
groupsEnter.append('foreignObject').attr('width', 100).attr('height', 100).attr('x', 20).attr('y', 20).append('input')
    .attr('type', 'checkbox').attr('class', 'check');
```

When I open the webpage, I can see in the inspector that the checkboxes are generated in the HTML, but they are not appearing on the website, nor can I hover over the checkbox HTML to see where they are located. However, very weirdly, when I manually change the HTML in the inspector to add the foreign object using the exact same HTML code generated for the checkboxes I added in D3, it seems to appear? I am quite confused and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell given only the short snippet you posted. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need an html body to render you checkbox

```
 groupsEnter.append("foreignObject")
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("x", 20)
      .attr("y", 20)
      .append("xhtml:body")
      .html("<form><input type=checkbox id=check/></form>")
```